# Output post category

Tags: craft3

I have created a blog channel and a blog category along with a category field.

Now I wish output the category within the blog post.

```twig
{% set categoryEntry = craft.categories().group('blog') %}
{% set categories = categoryEntry.all() %}

  {% for blogEntry in craft.entries.section('blogPosts').limit(8).all() %}
  <div class="blog card">
    <ul>
      <li>Article</li>
      <li>|</li>
      {% nav category in categories %}
      <li><a href="{{ category.url }}"></a>{{ category.title }}</a></li>
      {% endnav %}
    </ul>
    <h1>{{ blogEntry.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ blogEntry.excerpt }}</p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

My code outputs all categories rather than just the one assiotated with the post.

Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, you are loading *all* categories in the line `{% set categories = categoryEntry.all() %}` and that's why you are getting them all for each entries.

What you need to do is to fetch your categories in the context of your `blogEntry`.

Here I assume a field name of `blogCategories` on your `blogEntry` but change accordingly to match what your Categories field is call:

```twig
{% for blogEntry in craft.entries.section('blogPosts').limit(8).all() %}
  <div class="blog card">
    <ul>
      <li>Article</li>
      <li>|</li>
      {% nav category in blogEntry.blogCategories.all() %}
      <li><a href="{{ category.url }}"></a>{{ category.title }}</a></li>
      {% endnav %}
    </ul>
    <h1>{{ blogEntry.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ blogEntry.excerpt }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively (and probably best) you can eager-load your categories on your initial entries query:

```twig
{# Fetch your entries and eager-load your categories #}
{% set blogEntries = craft.entries()
  .section('blogPosts')
  .with(['blogCategories'])
  .limit(8)
  .all() %}

{% for blogEntry in blogEntries %}
  <div class="blog card">
    <ul>
      <li>Article</li>
      <li>|</li>
      {% nav category in blogEntry.blogCategories %}
      <li><a href="{{ category.url }}"></a>{{ category.title }}</a></li>
      {% endnav %}
    </ul>
    <h1>{{ blogEntry.title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ blogEntry.excerpt }}</p>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

You can read on eager-loading in the documentation here - https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html

Comment: Thanks very much, eager-loading looks interesting